# ¿como se pone un link a un div?

Tags: html, css

tengo puesto un link (href) a un texto pero necesito que lo tenga el div para que al sobrevolar el div, aparezca la mano de cuando hay un link
gracias anticipadas por vuestra ayuda!

```html
<div class="seguros">
    <a href="seguros.html"> >>>> Seguros & Hipotecas <<<<  </a>

    <p class="oculta"><b><br>Hipoteca:</b> EURIBOR + 0,99% (1er año 1.99%), te damos el 100% del valor</p>
    <p class="oculta"><b>Seguro de baja para autónomos:</b> desde 25€/mes cobra la baja completa al 5º día con sólo presentar el parte de baja!</p>
    <p class="oculta"><b>Invierte tus ahorros:</b> rentabilidad media 5,5%, inversión garantizada, sin impuestos a partir del 5º año!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desde HTML5 puedes englobar elementos de bloque dentro de links, por lo tanto, puedes sacar el link para que englobe todo el div. Para que no te ponga todo el texto subrayado puedes utilizar la propiedad `text-decoration: none`.

```css
#link{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="seguros.html">
  <div class="seguros">
      <h3> >>>> Seguros & Hipotecas <<<<  </h3>

      <p class="oculta"><b><br>Hipoteca:</b> EURIBOR + 0,99% (1er año 1.99%), te damos el 100% del valor</p>
      <p class="oculta"><b>Seguro de baja para autónomos:</b> desde 25€/mes cobra la baja completa al 5º día con sólo presentar el parte de baja!</p>
      <p class="oculta"><b>Invierte tus ahorros:</b> rentabilidad media 5,5%, inversión garantizada, sin impuestos a partir del 5º año!</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: me he explicado mal, que aparezca la mano  en cualquier lugar del div porque hay un enlace

Comment: @Basicmix ¿Cuál es el objetivo que pretendes conseguir? Intenta ser más detallado para poder modificar mi solución.

Comment: @Basicmix Vale, ¿y si le dan a cualquier parte del div que vaya a dicho enlace?

Comment: ahora me pierdo, necesito que al clicar cualquier parte del div, vayan a un enlace

Comment: @Basicmix He editado la respuesta. Creo que ahora si que es lo que buscas.

Comment: genial!!! está perfecto, veo que todo lo que quede dentro de la etiqueta "a" lo trata como un enlace. Muchas gracias Francisco!!!